# Objective-c Conditionally serve ViewControllers after app launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a question about loading view controllers when an app launches. I want to have a condition that checks when the application launches based upon stored core data values and if true, it will load the view controller second in the stack.  If false, I want to load the root view controller.  I want to always preserve the root view controller not matter what the result of the condition, I just want to skip loading this view if the result of my condition is true and go right to the second view in the stack.  I am not using storyboards.  Has anyone done anything of this nature before?
Now, having said that, is this logic flow an acceptable solution to be implementing.  Will there be issues during submission if I try something like this?

Comment: How are your views structured? Are you using UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I apologize.  I should have mentioned that in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early in your app's launch, like in `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, check the condition in question and, if true, push the second controller onto the navigation stack. Specify `NO` for the animation parameter so that there's no obvious transition.

You can also set the nav controller's `viewControllers` property directly. Set it to an array with first and second controllers if the condition is true, or just the first controller otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following view controllers:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
UIViewController *firstViewController;
UIViewController *secondViewController;
```

Then you can write code like this (**edit**: reworked solution based on comments below):

```
if (yourCondition)
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[ firstViewController, secondViewController ];
else
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[ secondViewController, firstViewController ];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer bgfriend0.  What I am looking to do is always have my navigation controller look like: navigationController.viewControllers = @[ firstViewController, secondViewController ];  Based upon my condition I just want to serve either view one or view two.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If you mean you want the viewController array to look like that but firstViewController be presented to the user (even though secondViewController is above it in the array), then you are trying to do something that navigation controller does not and was not meant to support. Perhaps try a different approach? I'm not entirely sure what you're after.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I will have to try a different approach. To try and reiterate what I was saying above.  I am looking to have a  normal stack of views ,viewControllerOne, viewControllerTwo, viewControllerThree etc...  If condition is true on load, then secondViewController is loaded as the first view.  If, the condition is false, then firstViewController is loaded as the first view.  The issue with your provided answer is I cannot pop back to the first view if I need to, if the secondViewController is loaded first.

Comment: Oh, well that sounds like a simple modification of the solution I posted above. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for reworking your solution.  What you have presented makes sense, but it does not enable me to pop back to the root view controller (firstViewController) if my condition is false.  Based upon your solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Check the conditions in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is the simple way.

However, we are suppose to keep the AppDelegate away from complicated. The best way to do the launching things, like check some condition, prepare the data, is to create a LaunchViewController as the rootViewController, you can make it the same looking as your app launch image. Then, you can presenting any VC you want with/without animation, it will be the first VC that user will see.

Let me know if you need more help.